# Bash can't create a file when calling from PHP

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell

newfile.php :

```
<?php
        $Name_File = $_GET['name'];

        $cmd1="sh /var/www/cgi-bin/newfile.sh".escapeshellarg($Name_File);
        exec("$cmd1");
?>
```

newfile.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash -x

echo "test"           >/var/named/chroot/var/named/$1.lan
```

I can't create a new file when triger from PHP, but when i type **sh newfile.sh** from my console it works. any help?

Comment: Surely the `$cmd` string needs a space after `newfile.sh`?

Comment: And you're assigning to `$cmd` and attempting to execute `$cmd1`.

Comment: sorry my mistake, both using $cmd1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss space in your command:

```
$cmd="sh /var/www/cgi-bin/newfile.sh ".escapeshellarg($Name_File);
```

that's why your script trying to execute:

```
sh /var/www/cgi-bin/newfile.shtest.txt
```

and exit with error: no such file or directory

Comment: ok i tried to put a space after /var/www/cgi-bin/newfile.sh but still no luck

Comment: Do you have privileges to create files in this directory? `/etc/var/named/chroot/var/named/`

Comment: Try to check your output: `exec("$cmd1",$output);print_r($output);`

Comment: And check path, may be your chroot (if used) jail your script and you need only `/var/named/$1.lan` and put your sh script in chroot enviroment.

Comment: already tried chmod +x newfile.sh & chmod u+x newfile.sh ; chmod 777 /etc/var/named/chroot/var/named/ & chmod 777 newfile.php. did i miss something? :(